# How to make RAM of client don't grow up when fetch API by React?

Tags: reactjs, memory

I'm using React to create a web app and get problem about RAM when I fetch API. The RAM of client grow up and don't stop. How can I fix it? And why the problem appears?
Here my code:

```
    class GetLoginInfo extends React.Component{
            constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = { isLoading: false}
            }

  CallApiInfo(){
    fetch('http://localhost:8070/' + request_info,{
  // mode: 'cors',
  signal: controller.signal,
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':"*",
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  method: "GET"
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: true,
    resultData: responseJson.status
  });
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
  }

  render(){
this.CallApiInfo();
result_data = this.state.resultData;
if (!this.state.isLoading) {
  return React.createElement('div',null,'Loading...');
}

return React.createElement('p',null,result_data );
  }
}
```

First, I think because variable. So I have ever reset state but it don't fix that.
And it looks like below:

```
    class GetLoginInfo extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    // this.state = { isLoading: true}
    this.state = this.getInitialState();
  }
  getInitialState(){
    const initialState = {
      isLoading: false
    };
    return initialState;
  }
  resetState(){
        this.setState(this.getInitialState());
  }
  CallApiInfo(){
    fetch('http://localhost:8070/' + request_info,{
  // mode: 'cors',
  signal: controller.signal,
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':"*",
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  method: "GET"
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      this.resetState();
      this.setState({
        isLoading: true,
    resultData: responseJson.status
  });
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
  }
```

Comment: did you get a response from API, it means you can save your data in the state or you get null data?

Comment: It's not a great idea to make a new API call every time the component renders...

Comment: You’re also never setting the loading state back to false, so it will always be Loading....

Comment: @Aras: I save my data. So what happen when I get null dataa?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah. I really new react dev, can you give some idea,please

Comment: @Jake Luby: yeah. I use the template in react doc. So, can you give some idea, please?